# Get number of siblings for a wp_nav_menu element

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a custom [Walker function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to customise the display of a menu in Wordpress.

To go one step forward I would like to have a different HTML markup for submenus with more than X elements.

Is there a way I can check the number of elements for a given *item* within the `start_el` function of the Walker `Walker_Nav_Menu`?

Comment: I think you would have to do this with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

It's not the simplest thing using the Walker class, so I thought of a solution using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the menu HTML and count the submenus children after the menu has been built (using the [`wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_menu-slug_items/) filter):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_{MENU_SLUG}_items', function( $items, $args ) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($items);

    // get the .sub-menu elements
    $submenus = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');

    // for each one if it has children add a class
    // like has-{num}-children
    foreach ($submenus as $ul) {
        if($ul->hasChildNodes()) {
            // number of child nodes divided by 2
            // to exclude the text nodes
            $numChildren = $ul->childNodes->length / 2;
            $class = "has-$numChildren-children";
            $ul->setAttribute(
                'class', $ul->getAttribute('class') . ' ' . $class
            );
        }
    }

    // save the changes
    $html = $dom->saveHtml($dom->documentElement);
    // remove html and body tags added by $dom->loadHTML
    $items = preg_replace('~</?(html|body)>~', '', $html);

    return $items;

}, 10, 2);
```

This should add a class `has-{num}-children` to every submenu with children (where `{num}` is the number of children), so that you can target whatever you want.

It can be easily changed to apply the class only to the submenus with a minimum number of children.

Remember to change `{MENU_SLUG}` with the slug of your menu.

Comment: Interesting approach. How would you access to the class later on in the Walker to get the number of siblings? Wouldn't it be easier to add a `data-siblings` attribute instead ?

Comment: You cannot access the class in the Walker because at this point the Walker has already finished: I'm working on the HTML produced by the Walker. In this case if you want to change some other parts of the submenu HTML markup (like adding an element) you can do it by changing the dom document.

Comment: Mmm... that's far from ideal. In that case I wouldn't even need the filter. I could directly work with jQuery.